# RoR: Test not running all assertions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm working through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and encountering an unusual testing issue.

In brief, the command 'bundle exec rake test' is not running all the 'assertions' every time which results in 'errors' being produced.

**1) When I first issue the command, I get the following result:**

$ bundle exec rake test

Run options: --seed 37842

## Running:

E........................E....E...

Finished in 1.076112s, 31.5952 runs/s, 123.5931 assertions/s.

1) Error:
UsersIndexTest#test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links:
AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'destroy' could not be found for UsersController
    test/integration/users_index_test.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
    test/integration/users_index_test.rb:20:in`block in '

2) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_destroy_when_logged_in_as_a_non-admin:
AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'destroy' could not be found for UsersController
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:57:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:56:in`block in '

3) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in:
AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'destroy' could not be found for UsersController
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:48:in`block in '

34 runs, 133 assertions, 0 failures, 3 errors, 0 skips

**2) When I immediately reissue the command without doing anything else, I get the following -- different -- result:**

$ bundle exec rake test

Run options: --seed 13168

## Running:

..................................

Finished in 1.065538s, 31.9088 runs/s, 129.5121 assertions/s.

34 runs, 138 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

**3) I'm running this in a Cloud9 environment on a MacBook Pro**

Thanks for the help.

Comment: if you run `bundle exec rake test TESTOPTS="--seed=37842"` will it fail again?

Comment: Yes, it still fails.

Comment: $ bundle exec rake test TESTOPTS="--seed=37842"

Run options: --seed=37842

# Running:

E........................E..E.....

Finished in 1.090838s, 31.1687 runs/s, 123.7580 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
UsersIndexTest#test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links:
AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'destroy' could not be found for UsersController
    test/integration/users_index_test.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
    test/integration/users_index_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
.
.
34 runs, 135 assertions, 0 failures, 3 errors, 0 skips

Comment: It seems like you have some order dependence in your tests. You can use [minitest-bisect](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest-bisect) to help you pin down which tests are causing the order depencence

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll see I can track it down from here.